# Can I use the connection string generated in the MongoDB Compass in Pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to MongoDB with python using Pymongo. The code I was using is:
`cluster=MongoClient("connection_String_url")`
The connection_String_url was generated in MongoDB Compass.  This command can be executed in python but it doesn't seem working because all the other operations that have used this cluster had the same error "Server Selection Timeout Error: SSL handshake failed".

Base on some other answers I tried "ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE" but not working either with the error: not authorized on admin to execute command. The `MongoClient("connection_String_url",ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)`command can also be executed through.

I was just wondering if it is because of my code or this "connection_String_url" just cannot be used in this case because i see people using Altas connection string in this case normally.

Comment: Please add the connection string you are using to help us help you. You should redact the password.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for this for a while, since I've been used to using MongoDB compass with Node.js projects. With that said, the following code worked for me to connect. The connection string is pasted exactly from the MongoDB Compass Cluster information (with sensitive information removed).

```
import pymongo
maxSevSelDelay = 1
try:
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<MONGO CLUSTER>.mongodb.net/<DB NAME>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&w=majority&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&retryWrites=true&ssl=true",
                             serverSelectionTimeoutMS=maxSevSelDelay)
    client.server_info() 

except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as err:
    print(err)
```